# Difference between gradle bootrun and bootjar/build in a springboot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, jruby

I'm working in a quite complex app that for some reason, `gradle bootRun` works as expected but when `gradle bootjar` or `gradle build` is used to then execute the packaged jar with `java -jar pathtojar`, it fails to load some jruby scripts present in a dependency.

What are the differences between those two in terms of packaging and how can `bootRun` be more reliable?